# Partial Order and scroll ResultSet

Tags: oracle

Following Problem:

Two tables T1 and T2. Both tables are joined and the result is sorted by T1.A, T2.A, T1.B. The result consists of >10Mio entries. There is only a need of the first 10 rows of the result.

Since we have an orderby oracle will order everything and then will start to present results. This is unefficient.

Testing by removing sorting by T2.A and using a special index (T1.A, T1.B, T1.C, T1.D) where T1.C and T1.D are part of the where clause. This works wonders, oracle does not use a sort at all but needs to be forced by a hint to use the index. (unlucky as well).

The next idea is to sort the partial result of T1 by T1.A initially using a special Index(T1.A, T1.C, T1.D) and after that lets Oracle do its job. Since Oracle pulls out results being already sorted by T1.A the question is if Oralce only needs to read the first x entries (until a new T1.A value is encountered) to present the first result saving lots of lookups or is it not that smart and still sorts every potential results even if the result it has are already correctly partially sorted by T1.A? I even think that group by T1.A might help here if I remember its usecases correctly.

Has someone additional information or can at best verify that this will work? Any hint will be great.

[update]

Some Pseudo Code:

SELECT Person.Name, Person.Amount FROM Person, Income WHERE Person.Name = Income.Name Ordered By Person.Name, Income.Amount, Person.Position

We want to list the first 10 Persons and skip the rest. Currently Oracle selects all results, sort it and return. That is not effective. Since this is a simplified version of the problem it might look to obvious. We have Oracle choosing a cartesien product for instance. I try the first index hint for sure.

But we have no combined index (sort statement spans more than one index). Materialized view is out of reach since we have a legacy 3rd party code and we dont want to create precaluclated views for every lets say 100 queries in question. We need a solution on either rewrite a request partially or add hints / indexes etc.

So the idea is to know if Oracle sees this:

SELECT Person.Name, Person.Amount FROM (SELECT Person.Name, Person.Position FROM Person ORDER BY Person.Name), Income WHERE Person.Name = Income.Name ORDER BY Person.Name, Income.Amount, Person.Position

And for calculating the first 20 results it is smart enough to only collect the persons with the same name and sorting them by income since the persons are already sorted by name. So to calculate the first batch (number of persons) with the same name it just retrieves the persons with that name (already presorted) until it discovers a person with a different name - so Oracle can be sure to know all the persons with a particular name.

That is the question I try to solve.

Thanks.

Comment: What would be the indexes on the example you provided (person and income)?

Comment: I did a benchmark of an oracle 11g installation and he does not sort partially. The trace shows an access of over a million rows in order to answer 50 first resulting rows meaning it still sorts the stuff at the end. It is something I did in 2008 in a similar situation and was disappointed since this is the most obvious situation required. I will do a 12c benchmark this week and post the result. I also do a PostgreSQL benchmark on this issue. Since I always loved PostgreSQL I hope they also solve this problem right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it turns out that Oracle can not do this. I expected Oracle to know and value certain sorting oders and information but yet it is not clever enough (at least as it appears).

To sum it up again so every one may understand it:

You have the following result set:

`A | B | C (attributes)
 1 | 1 | 3
 1 | 3 | 3
 1 | 4 | 1
 1 | 1 | 2
 2 | 1 | 1
 ...`

As you can see the logical result set is alread sorted towards A (thats what I tell Oracle by hints or using a sub-select with order by). Also a capable optimizer should know that it can presort at least A since it comes from a single table.

Now that A is already sorted, to return the first row (and even more in this example) all Oracle must do to ORDER BY A,B,C is to read entry 1 to 4 sort them and that it wont need to access and regard entry 5 is obvious since the value of A changes. So it is not elevant for answering the first four result entries. This way oracle will never need to access more information than this.

Thats how I would expect calculation being done. Even if I give the hint that Oracle should only prepare 10 entries it is still reading a million test records to find the fist x records. It is a problem I remember having investigated in 2008 and it is still not present... I am disappointed.

Almost every performance issue I have with a certain progam focus around a sort spanning more than one table.

Remember what a usual web / Rest interfaces does... it filters, it sorts and it presents the first x entries (or a pagination). So why is Oracle wasting time here? I talk about accessing a million entries instead of the first 500 or so (my live data problem). It does not make sense.

So thanks for your afford. Thanks all of you. Lets hope Oracle might be able to this in a later version.

Hopefully PostgreSQL will do this properly... .

Comment: from what i understand from your answer even if oracle in clever enough it still has to do a scan of table A for sorting ????

Comment: No quite right. Oracle seams to not value the information that if you have a alread partially presorted set it can not just apply additional sortig to get the complete sorting right. Sorting in a specific order over more than one column is associative sort(rows, A,B,C) = sort(sort(sort(rows, A), B), C). That is the information that Oracle 11g does not value and reuse. We still have not tested Oracle 12c yet but I wouldnt think they had added this feature otherwise they would have used it for advertising or at least it would be part of the release notes.

Comment: And this explains why Oracle is preferring a full table scan or other non-sorted indexes instead of using an index in the right sort order even it know we want just 100 rows instead of half a million in full table scan. Thats a shame but I remember being partly unsorted in 2008 about Oracle myself. :) Would be nice if one knows if PostgreSQL already knows about this... .

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to simulate a fast response time for the first rows in a query similar to yours was adding and index to the key fields on each side of the join.

In your example that means:

- Person has an index on the name and position fields.
- Income has an index on name and amount fields.
- Since Person.name equals Income.name, your sort should be income.name, income.amount, person.position.

This way, Oracle has a chance of avoid the lengthy SORT operation on the finished join since everything that is joined was already pre sorted.

Avoid adding other columns not in the indexes or even a * since it will make it less likely that the optimizer will use the indexes alone. Hints are probably going to be ignored if that is the case.

Edit =>

I added the indexes below:

```
create index oe.ORDERS_IX_7 on oe.orders (order_id,order_mode)
create index oe.ORDERS_ITEMS_IX_7 on oe.order_items (order_id,unit_price)
```

And tried:

```
select oe.orders.order_id,oe.orders.order_mode 
   from oe.order_items,oe.orders
   where orders.order_id = order_items.order_id
   order by oe.order_items.order_id,order_items.unit_price,oe.orders.order_mode
```

The execution plan looks like

```
SORT
    HASH JOIN
       INDEX FULL SCAN   ORDER_ITEMS_IX_7
       INDEX FULL SCAN   ORDER_IX_7
```

Then I tried:

```
select o.order_id,o.order_mode, i.unit_price 
  from 
   (SELECT order_id, unit_price FROM oe.order_items order by order_id, unit_price) i,
   (select order_id, order_mode from oe.orders order by order_id,order_mode) o
  where O.order_id = i.order_id


MERGE JOIN
   INDEX FULL SCAN      ORDERS_IX_7
   SORT (JOIN)
      INDEX FULL SCAN   ORDER_ITEMS_IX_7
```

I don't have enough volume to test this, but based on the execution plan, both are going to be much faster than what you are getting now with a sort operation over full table scans. For simplicity, I would prefer the first option if the performance in comparable.

Comment: Please check the explain path and the performance measurement. If oracle only access lets say 101 rows to answer 100 rows, i would love to see your explains / measures. Would be great.

Comment: Martin, I added two different examples using new indexes.

Comment: Can you give me traces of them both. The most important part is that you limit the result to the first lets say 50 rows. In a where clause put rownum < 50 but beware the where clause is regarded before the sort. So putting a rownum in a where of a select that will lead to a false answer since it sorts the 50 first entries not all entries and give you the first 50 correct results.

Comment: In my traces this still results in a full access of the table meaning a full sort. But my scenario is slightly different.

Comment: Depending on the columns that you add to the select, unfortunately it does go back to the sort operation. I don't have enough data to test how fast the first rows get returned (which is your ultimate goal, not how many rows it goes through).  I was able to add non indexed fields from ORDERS, but not from ORDER_ITEMS without changing the plan.  How did that affect performance? As long as you don't have a separate SORT operation on the result of your join, you should get a pretty fast response time for the first rows.

Answer (score 0):

You should try a FIRST_ROWS hint - if the optimizer knows you only want the top 10 rows, it will optimize index access accordingly.

Another Option is PLSQL - you can open the cursors on the sorted SELECTS and only retrieve the matching rows.

But with up-to-date statistics this should even work with the original query if it is formulated correctly. But without you showing us code, we can just guess.

Comment: The problem is the sort. In order to sort correctly Oracle does a sort at the end. The idea is having a partially sorted table to join this. The idea is to have oracle stop after reading some lines and not load all entries, do the join, do the sort -> Answer the first row. This requires some additional logic for oracle and I am uncertain if oracle does have that kind of brains.

Comment: if all three columns are indexed, the Optimizer may choose to do explicit index based access if it knows only some rows are required. It could access the firs rows of each index first and join them. If it won't do this I would write a pipelined table function which joins explicitly with 2 open cursors

Answer (score 0):

After testing in Oracle 11g restricting the no of rows to 10 in one of the tables doubled  the performance.Also using order by of one of the table had no effect on cost.

```
SELECT Person1.Name, Person1.Amount 
FROM (select * from (SELECT Person.Name, Person.Position 
FROM Person ORDER BY Person.Name)
where rownum <=10) Person1, Income 
WHERE Income.Name=Person1.Name 
ORDER BY Person1.Name, Income.Amount, Person1.Position
```

**Explain Plan for three cases**

**1)Original select**
[link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aErm3.jpg)

**2)Select after order by of one table** [link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8BsV.jpg)

**3)Select after restricting to select 10 rows of one table**
[link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdxf7.jpg)

Comment: You still have the same problem. The idea was to let Oracle compute the results without touching every entry of the table. Having a outter sort being performed Oracle is not valuing the partial sorting order that already may exist. Found out that Oracle is still not clever enough.